# Advices for MYSQL optimization with heavy tables

Tags: mysql, laravel

We have a cryptocurrency platform made with PHP (Laravel) and MYSQL, we had some MYSQL problems on last months because of our big tables (1million+ rows). Seems that MYSQL can't work with so many rows (if I have a "SELECT * LIMIT 10" with 10 users at the same time the MYSQL never respond any request).

We fixed those problems by splitting those rows in two tables, one that is like a "backup" and one that is constantly used (with just some rows).

But for now we're facing a problem because our main table "Users" is being heavy (300,000 rows) and I don't think we can split this table, also don't think this is the best way to work.

This is our first project and we do not have much knowledge on database technology, can you please give us some advice on how to solve this kind of problem? Should we migrate to other database like Postgres?

Our server is a aws 96core 185GB ram and it never hit 100% usage.

Comment: We need more details about the table structure, how it's indexed, and a better view of your actual query. MySQL can absolutely handle 1 million+ rows, and I have seen much larger.

Comment: Additionally, VMs can be configured in ways that don't lead to great disk performance, so that's another thing to look at. My initial guess is that your actual query is causing MySQL to run over the whole table before it limits anything.

Comment: @Jacobm001 It's strange because if I do only one simple select query it will respond in like 1~3 seconds, but if I do like 10 at the same time it just stuck forever... (I'm not using transactions or lock on this table). I'll post more information soon.

Comment: mysql can handle it. If you were doing the same query from 10 connections at the same time, it should cache it and be instant. Something else is going on.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey the queries are never the same, mostly because the table is changing 100% of the time, and the WHERE statements are not the same too. But i found that we are not using the INDEX right, I'm optimizing this right now, thanks.

Comment: migrate to PostgreSQL ... it's way more flexible and scalable than MySQL ...

Comment: `LIMIT 10` will come back almost immediately; what else is in the query?  Maybe a `GROUP BY`  Or an `ORDER BY`?  And multiple queries at the same time is not likely to hurt.